# Error after trying to install php5-mcrypt on Debian Squeeze

Tags: debian, php5, apt, debian-squeeze, php-mcrypt

I want to install php5-mcrypt, but I get this error after entering a

```
apt-get install php5-mcrypt
```

Error:

```
php5-mcrypt : Hängt ab von: php5-common (= 5.3.3-7+squeeze15) aber 5.3.9-1~dotdeb.2 soll installiert werden
```

Error (translated):

```
php5-mcrypt : Depends on: php5-common (= 5.3.3-7+squeeze15) but 5.3.9-1~dotdeb.2 should be installed
```

My sources.list:

```
# squeeze packages
deb http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/ squeeze main contrib non-free
deb-src http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/ squeeze main contrib non-free
deb http://security.debian.org/ squeeze/updates main
deb-src http://security.debian.org/ squeeze/updates main
```

Comment: apt-get update ?

Comment: Was the first step. Sorry, I didn't write this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you had different repository sources in the past and you tried to install from them:

- the official Debian repository
- the unofficial [dotdeb.org](http://www.dotdeb.org) repository

The `php5-common` package coming from [dotdeb.org](http://www.dotdeb.org) is currently marked to be installed, although you don't have the dotdeb.org source present anymore.  And the `php5-mcrypt` package you're trying to install is coming from the official Debian repository and is from an older version, hence the discrepancy.

To solve that, you have 2 options:

1. You go with the [dotdeb.org](http://www.dotdeb.org) repository and you [add it back to your sources](http://www.dotdeb.org/instructions/), you `apt-get update` and you try to install again.
2. You keep only packages coming from the official Debian repo, so you should prevent the installation of the `php5-common` (and any other package coming from [dotdeb.org](http://www.dotdeb.org) or other unofficial repo and marked to be installed).  This can be done with `apt-get remove php5-common`

Comment: Okay. And what happens to the other packages?  `dpkg --list | grep dotdeb` throws:  `libapache2-mod-php5, php5, php5-cgi, php5-cli, php5-common, php5-curl, php5-gd, php5-imap, php5-mysql, php5-sqlite, php5-suhosin and php5-xsl`

Comment: I installed it via dotdeb and made an upgrade from PHP5.3 to 5.4. Thank you!

Comment: If you had multiple packages marked to be installed from dotdeb, you would have needed to remove them all (if staying with official Debian packages only).  But in my experience dotdeb packages are quite stable and provide an easy way to have a more up to date PHP.

Comment: @StinsonMaster Can you up vote my answer as it seems it did satisfy you?  That usually is [the practice on SE.](http://serverfault.com/help/someone-answers) Thanks!

Comment: Yes, but it is not possible to vote if you have less then 15 reputations ;)

Comment: In my case it might help to specify the version `apt-get install php5-mcrypt=5.3.3-7+squeeze15`.